# 'TypeError: decoding str is not supported' when concatenating in udf pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a simple UDF that concatenates 2 strings and a separator.

```py
def stringConcat(separator: str, first: str, second: str):
    return first + separator + second
spark.udf.register("stringConcat_udf", stringConcat)
customerDf.select("firstname", "lastname", stringConcat_udf(lit("-"),"firstname", 
"lastname")).show()
```

This is the traceback:

> An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: decoding str is not supported'. Full traceback
> below:
> TypeError: decoding str is not supported

What is wrong with this?

Comment: udfs are slow and they are the last line of defense. Deafeats purpose to use udf to concat. Please dont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, PySpark already has a function called `concat_ws` ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html)) which does just that:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn
customerDf.select("firstname", "lastname", fn.concat_ws("-","firstname", "lastname").alias("joined")).show()
```

But if you still want to define this UDF, the `spark.udf.register("stringConcat_udf", stringConcat)` isn't stored anywhere, which means it's usable in spark queries, but you'd need to define it to use with pyspark dataframes ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html#use-udf-with-dataframes)):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
stringConcat_udf = fn.udf(stringConcat, StringType())
customerDf.select("firstname", "lastname", stringConcat_udf(fn.lit("-"),"firstname", "lastname").alias("joined")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

After registering your UDF, you can call it using `expr`. Try this:

```
customerDf.select("firstname", "lastname", expr('stringConcat_udf("-", firstname, lastname)'))
```

This works:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
customerDf = spark.createDataFrame([('Tom', 'Hanks')], ["firstname", "lastname"])

def stringConcat(separator: str, first: str, second: str):
    return first + separator + second
spark.udf.register("stringConcat_udf", stringConcat)
df = customerDf.select("firstname", "lastname", F.expr('stringConcat_udf("-", firstname, lastname)'))
df.show()
# +---------+--------+----------------------------------------+
# |firstname|lastname|stringConcat_udf(-, firstname, lastname)|
# +---------+--------+----------------------------------------+
# |      Tom|   Hanks|                               Tom-Hanks|
# +---------+--------+----------------------------------------+
```